# How to create a loop using a button?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a group of merged cells with a number.

When a user clicks a button I want the number to increment by 1. On click again, increment by 1, then click again, decrease by 2 back to the original number.

```
Sub OnClickLetterSent()
If Worksheets("Lettersent").Range.Value = 802 Then
    Worksheets("Lettersent").Range.Value = Worksheets("Lettersent").Range("A1:E14") + 1
ElseIf Worksheets("Lettersent").Range.Value = 803 Then
    Worksheets("Lettersent").Range.Value = Worksheets("Lettersent").Range("A1:E14") + 1
ElseIf Worksheets("Lettersent").Range.Value = 804 Then
    Worksheets("Lettersent").Range.Value = Worksheets("Lettersent").Range("A1:E14") - 2
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) You're not specifying a range in your `IF` statement: `Worksheets("Lettersent").Range.Value` should be something like `Worksheets("Lettersent").Range("A1").Value`. 2) Do you really want to change *all* the values in `A1:E14`?

Comment: Well I was using a merged cell in order to make the number bigger. Should I use just a single cell enlarged to fit the number?

Comment: Merged cells are a VBA nightmare. If you plan using them, know it's just the topleft cell displaying it's value

Comment: JvdV that was perfect, when I changed it to just A1 as the cell reference it works perfect, now I need to work on change the background color as they click.

Comment: Cyber why did you delete. I was about to upvote you and say that your answer is perfect.

Comment: Because @Tim Williams ' answer was more elegant than mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the top-left cell of your merged range is A1 then:

```
Sub OnClickLetterSent()
    With Worksheets("Lettersent").Range("A1")
        Select Case .Value 
            Case 802, 803: .Value = .Value + 1
            Case 804: .Value = 802
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try:

```
With Worksheets("Lettersent").Range("A1")
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Choose(.Value - 801, 803, 804, 802)
End With
```

Or:

```
With Worksheets("Lettersent")
    .[A1] = .[A1+CHOOSE(A1-801,1,1,-2)]
End With
```